# How can I easily copy the whole CSS file from a website?

Tags: css, developer-tools

How can I easily copy the whole CSS file a website uses to stylize HTML with Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera?

With the web inspector, I can see the css styles applied to an element, but I can't see the big picture of styles applied to the whole HTML document.

Can you show me how can I do this?

Comment: Very easily. The CSS link source is in the page source. Surely web inspector shows clickable links to the CSS files?

Comment: I'm looking for tools to do this, browser addons, etc...

Comment: If you are looking for tools then this answer will be helpful. You can download the HTML page with all CSS, JS, Fonts and Image files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76445309/10461328

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For chrome you can use [Quick Source Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-source-viewer/cfmcghennfbpmhemnnfjhkdmnbidpanb) to see all CSS, whether in the `body` or the `head`, whether in the served HTML or injected at runtime.

It is better than the dev tools as you don't have to go looking for the `style` tags, and saving them is just a right click on the link.

Comment: I like that it's pretty printed, dev tools doesnt pretty print CSS yet

Comment: It does work nicely, but it does have some limitations--seem to just stop if it gets denied on certain pages. I was looking for one that could prod into certain external pages (the ones that are public, of course, not the private ones) as well, for restyle purposes because I am making styles for visually impaired and hue sensitive people. Also noticed that you have to re-refresh pages sometimes in order to get all the sources.

Answer (score 4):

The answer given by Bobby Russell is not correct in this case.
Just follow the steps:
Open the Firefox and type google.com in the url
Now Inspect the googlepage with the help of firebug.
You can see in the attached image how to select the css file
[image]

[image]

Comment: Download both images and see in zoom mode!

Comment: I see nothing on the picture, it can't be made bigger.

Comment: If you don't see the image, just right click and `open image in new tab`

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click the page and view the source.

   Ctrl+F link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="

   Follow the link

   See the CSS

Not too hard...right?

Comment: this way wont work for injected content. And wont find things that don't conform to that string; like embedded styles, or external styles with the `rel` and `type` the other way around etc. To fix this answer would make it complicated, and thus, not easy

Comment: Yes, this is a pretty glib answer, but it is easy to do and will work for many sites. The more complicated answer I guess is to look in the `<head>` portion of a given page and poke around. Firebug works, but only for Firefox, so I don't think that that's an acceptable answer either.